# Time for two relativistic objects to meet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

How do you prove that the time for two objects traveling towards each other at relativistic velocities is still d/(v1+v2).  Answer seems to have something to do with velocity addition but I'm stumped...

Comment: That's simply the usual definition of velocity in YOUR coordinate system: the ratio of YOUR distance traveled and YOUR time take to travel that distance. It doesn't get complicated until you ask the question what these distances, times and velocities look like for someone else who is traveling with a velocity relative to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two 'types' of velocities, relative velocities and mutual velocities.  The relative velocity between object A and B is the velocity of A (say) as seen by B, to find relative velocities you use the Lorentz-velocity addition formula. The mutual velocity of two objects is the rate of change of the distance between them as seen by an observer another frame. This is what you have. Mutual velocities (unlike relative velocities) can be greater then the speed of light (and in fact as large as $2c$) and are calculated  the way you have described.

Think about it, if you see object A and object B at a separation of $d$ and A is travelling at $v_1$ and $B$ is at $v_2$ then the distance travelled by each is:
$$d_A=v_1t$$
$$d_B=v_2t$$
But you know that $d_A+d_B=d$ so:
$$(v_1+v_2)t=d$$
$$t=\frac{d}{v_1+v_2}$$
This is simply from the definition of velocity.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is really helpful.  I suppose I was making the problem harder than it was supposed to be.  They don't actually ask you to calculate the velocity of A from the rest frame of B (or vice versa) so I suppose the point is that ordinary rules of velocity addition apply between two objects viewed from the perspective of an inertial frame in which both A and B are moving.